# Austria - How much if enough

Tags: immigration, austria, salary, cost-of-living

I do not live in Europe, so I have no idea what living costs are. I would like to know whether a salary of about 5000 euro per month would be sufficient to live in Söll, Austria? Now I know there are many factors to take into consideration, but I'm just looking for a ball park figure / an average.

Comment: That's five times of the minimum wage in Austria, even after taxes that should be more than enough to live, but that depends on your lifestyle as well. You can usually check numbeo to get a ballpark estimate of the living costs: https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/country_result.jsp?country=Austria

Comment: @SztupY many thanks for the information. I'm a software architect. I'll have a look at numbeo

Comment: Many many people live on less so it's *sufficient*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_average_wage Beyond that, there are indeed many factors and asking for a "ball park figure" does not make the question more answerable.

Comment: One other thing to check is glassdoor for salaries around the place you're goind to live to check if your given salary is above or below average: https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salaries/austria-software-architect-salary-SRCH_IL.0,7_IN18_KO8,26.htm

Comment: I'm closing as a duplicate of the other one as the general solution of numbeo+glassdoor applies here as well

Comment: Living in Austria, the 2555 average from Wikipedia still feels too much. ... Without children, in a small flat etc., living with 1000 net is perfectly possible.

Comment: Another note: Austrias income tax and mandatory health/retirement/unemployment insurance have a more-than-linear increase with higher incomes (up to a certain max value). With 1000 gross, about 850 net is realistic (although it depends on many things); but with 5000 gross, it's just about 3000 net for the same situation. (Still, 3000 is more than enough for a normal lifestyle)

Comment: And a last note: Söll + Software Architect sounds strange. Söll is a town with about 3000 people.

Comment: @deviantfan Software development requires a good laptop as well as a fast Internet connection. I've been working from home for the last two years. My employer has no issues with where I live, just as long as I complete the projects. Thanks for all the information!

Comment: @RichardBailey `requires a good laptop as well as a fast Internet connection ... My employer has no issues with where I live` Ah, then it's less of a problem :)